# Devexpress Report Designer - Create a table with multiple data member without using sql script

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm working on a report using devexpress report designer
and somehow I have columns that are from different data members
is there a way to display the values I needed without using SQL script
just C#?

I'm Expecting to display all data from different data members